# What's up with console colors in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jetty

When launching application with run-jetty-run plugin, it writes full output in Console only in red (error color).

How to make it write in right normal color?

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by our code , we use system.err to print those messages.

If you don't like it , we could use system.out to print it next version.

Feel free to post issues in our issue tracker.
http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/issues/list